# remote script execution

Tags: powershell

I have a series of scripts that I need to run in a DevOps environment; certain routines cannot be executed directly within a session and yet still need to be supported. The following script is what I've come up with after much trial and error. It seems to do exactly what I need but I am curious if there is anything that could be improved.

**Usage:**

```
./Invoke-ScriptOnRemoteMachine.ps1 `
    -ComputerName 'MyMachine' `
    -Restart `
    -ScriptPath 'C:/Temp/MyScript.ps1' `
    -UserName 'SomeUser' `
    -UserPassword 'It''s a secret to everybody!';
```

**Code:**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
[Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("PSAvoidUsingPlainTextForPassword", "UserPassword")]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [int]$Port = 5986,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch]$Restart,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch]$RunViaScheduledTask,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$ScriptPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [ValidateSet('classic', 'core')]
    [string]$ShellType = 'core',
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$UserName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$UserPassword
);

$ErrorActionPreference = [Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Stop;
$ProgressPreference = [Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::SilentlyContinue;
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = (
        [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor `
        [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
    );

$credential = [Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new(
        $UserName,
        (ConvertTo-SecureString `
            -AsPlainText `
            -Force `
            -String $UserPassword)
    );
$idleTimeoutInMilliseconds = ((New-Timespan -Minutes 13).TotalMilliseconds);
$shellName = 'pwsh.exe';

if ('classic' -eq $ShellType) {
    $shellName = 'powershell.exe';
}

Invoke-Command `
    -ComputerName $ComputerName `
    -Credential $credential `
    -Port $Port `
    -ScriptBlock {
        function Invoke-ScheduledTask {
            param(
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
                [string[]]$Arguments,
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                [string]$Command,
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
                [string]$TaskName = '',
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                [string]$UserName,
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
                [string]$UserPassword,
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
                [switch]$Wait
            );

            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($TaskName)) {
                $TaskName = (New-Guid).ToString();
            }

            $logFilePath = [IO.Path]::Combine([IO.Path]::GetTempPath(), "${TaskName}.log");
            $executionTimeLimit = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 59);
            $scheduledTaskArguments = @{ Execute = 'cmd'; };
            $trigger = New-CimInstance `
                -CimClass (Get-CimClass `
                    -ClassName 'MSFT_TaskRegistrationTrigger' `
                    -Namespace 'Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler') `
                -ClientOnly;

            if (($null -ne $Arguments) -and (0 -ne $Arguments.Count)) {
                $scheduledTaskArguments.Argument = "$($Arguments -Join ' ')";
            }

            $scheduledTaskArguments.Argument = "/c ${Command} $($scheduledTaskArguments.Argument) 2>&1 > `"${logFilePath}`"";
            $trigger.EndBoundary = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($executionTimeLimit.TotalMinutes + 1).ToString('s');

            New-ScheduledTask `
                -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction @scheduledTaskArguments) `
                -Description 'Created via automation.' `
                -Principal (New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal `
                    -LogonType 'Password' `
                    -RunLevel 'Highest' `
                    -UserId $UserName) `
                -Settings (New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
                    -AllowStartIfOnBatteries `
                    -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter ([TimeSpan]::Zero) `
                    -DisallowDemandStart `
                    -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries `
                    -ExecutionTimeLimit $executionTimeLimit) `
                -Trigger $trigger |
                Register-ScheduledTask `
                    -Password $UserPassword `
                    -TaskName $TaskName `
                    -TaskPath '\' `
                    -User $UserName |
                    Out-Null;

            if ($Wait) {
                do {
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 13;
                } while ('Running' -eq (Get-ScheduledTask -ErrorAction ([Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::SilentlyContinue) -TaskName $TaskName).State);

                Get-Content -Path $logFilePath; # TODO: Refactor so that log contents are emitted periodically.
            }
        }

        $ErrorActionPreference = [Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Stop;
        $ProgressPreference = [Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::SilentlyContinue;

        $arguments = @(
                '-ExecutionPolicy', ([Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy]::Unrestricted).ToString(),
                '-NoLogo',
                '-NonInteractive',
                '-File', "`"$($PSSenderInfo.ApplicationArguments.ScriptPath)`""
            );

        if ($PSSenderInfo.ApplicationArguments.RunViaScheduledTask) {
            Invoke-ScheduledTask `
                -Arguments $arguments `
                -Command ($PSSenderInfo.ApplicationArguments.ShellName) `
                -UserName ($PSSenderInfo.ApplicationArguments.UserName) `
                -UserPassword ($PSSenderInfo.ApplicationArguments.UserPassword) `
                -Wait;
        }
        else {
            & $PSSenderInfo.ApplicationArguments.ShellName @arguments;
        }

        if ($PSSenderInfo.ApplicationArguments.Restart) {
            Write-Host 'restart pending';
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 13;
            Restart-Computer;
        }
    } `
    -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption `
        -ApplicationArguments @{
            Restart = $Restart.ToBool();
            RunViaScheduledTask = $RunViaScheduledTask.ToBool();
            ScriptPath = $ScriptPath;
            ShellName = $shellName;
            UserName = $UserName;
            UserPassword = $UserPassword;
        } `
        -IdleTimeout $idleTimeoutInMilliseconds `
        -SkipCACheck) `
    -UseSSL;

if ($Restart) {
    $attemptDelayTimeInSeconds = 13;
    $commandTimeoutInMinutes = 17;
    $currentNumberOfAttempts = 0;
    $isRestartPending = $false;
    $maximumNumberOfAttempts = (($commandTimeoutInMinutes * 60) / $attemptDelayTimeInSeconds);

    do {
        try {
            $isRestartPending = (Invoke-Command `
                -ComputerName $ComputerName `
                -Credential $credential `
                -Port $Port `
                -ScriptBlock {
                    $isRestartPending = $false;

                    @(
                        'HKLM:/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Component Based Servicing/PackagesPending',
                        'HKLM:/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Component Based Servicing/RebootInProgress',
                        'HKLM:/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Component Based Servicing/RebootPending'
                    ) | ForEach-Object {
                        $isRestartPending = ($isRestartPending -bor (Test-Path -Path $_));
                    };

                    return $isRestartPending;
                } `
                -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption `
                    -IdleTimeout $idleTimeoutInMilliseconds `
                    -SkipCACheck) `
                -UseSSL);
        }
        <#
            "Pokemon exception handling" is considered the best option here as all errors we
            are likely to encounter will be related to the fact that the system is still in
            the process of restarting.
        #>
        catch {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $attemptDelayTimeInSeconds;
        }
    } while ($isRestartPending -and ($maximumNumberOfAttempts -gt ++$currentNumberOfAttempts));

    Write-Host 'restart completed';
}
```